# Selenium python to get the list of 4xx and 5xx of the resources (images,scripts,css) in a website

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently opening a website and getting the response code for the website.Next I am trying to get the count of 4xx and 5xx of the resources(javascript/images/css) that is loaded in the website. I am using Selenium with Python and ChromeDriver to perform this action.

```
driver.get(url)
reqs = requests.get(url)
print(reqs.status_code)
```

Comment: OP, please understand that this isn't a community where you literally ask for the solution. The current code, as it stands, is a simple getting of status_code. What code are you using to traverse to the resources via Selenium?

Comment: @Nogurenn
Sorry, I am not looking for a solution. I am trying to use browsermob-proxy and har file to get. the data that I am looking for but not being successful on navigating the har file –